# Mail Send Exception in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, gmail

I am trying to send emails using spring boot, but gettin error
I'm using 11JDK ,login information are all correct. I did everything as in a video but I'm in trouble
less secure apps enabled

Error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
```

aplication properties:

```
server.port=80
server.error.include-message=always
spring.mail.username=username@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.test-connection=false

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

My code:

```
@Service
public class EmailService {
    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender sender;
    public ApiResponse sendText(String email) {
        try {
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            mailMessage.setText("This message from Spring Boot Application");
            mailMessage.setSubject("Spring Boot Mail Message");
            mailMessage.setTo(email);
            sender.send(mailMessage);
            return new ApiResponse("Sent", true);
        } catch (MailException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ApiResponse("Error", false);
        }
    }
}
Controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmailController {
    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;
    @GetMapping("/sendText/{email}")
    public HttpEntity<?> sendText(@PathVariable String email) {
        ApiResponse apiResponse = emailService.sendText(email);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(apiResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998196/spring-boot-email-sending-throws-sockettimeoutexception-read-timed-out?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gmail as mail server you need to allow less secure apps to be able to send mails. see the following link for how to enable this: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: It's been allowed. Problem is not there